# Pulling EventLogs using powershell from a certain time period

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script that will pull application event logs from between 2 certain times. I have the following code:

```
$Begin = Get-Date -Date '2/04/2022 14:36:00'
$End = Get-Date -Date '2/04/2022 14:40:00'
Get-EventLog –LogName Application -After $Begin -Before $End
```

I keep receiving the following error.

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Date' is specified more 
than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple 
values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error with either of the `Get-Date` statements in your post. Did you perhaps try and combine them like `$begin,$end = Get-Date -Date '2/04/2022 14:36:00' -Date '2/04/2022 14:40:00'` or similar? Please make sure the code you've posted is actually the code you're running :)

Answer (score 1):

[Get-Eventlog itself is depreciated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1#description)

You can use Get-Winevent like js2010 is suggesting.
-filterhashtable is (I believe) the only way to specify a time period.

```
    $EventLogFilter = @{
        Logname = 'System'
        StartTime = [datetime]::Today.AddHours(-$Hours)
        EndTime = [datetime]::Today
    }
```

This would give you everything that happened in the last number of $hours you specify.

[This is a list of key-value pairs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-get-winevent-queries-with-filterhashtable?view=powershell-7.2#hash-table-key-value-pairs)

Answer (score 0):

An example with get-winevent's filterhashtable.  Any string that can be converted to a datetime would work.  Searching every log would require a foreach-object loop.

```
get-winevent -filterhashtable @{logname = 'application'; starttime = '12:45 pm'; 
  endtime = '12:50 pm' }


   ProviderName: gupdate

TimeCreated                      Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                      -- ---------------- -------
2/7/2022 12:45:19 PM              0
```